Error deploying llama-3 8B in sagemaker: tokenizer mismatch?
I get the following error in sagemaker code editor when trying to deploy meta/llama-3-8B-Instruct:
"The tokenizer class you load from this checkpoint is not the same type as the class this function is called from. It may result in unexpected tokenization.
The tokenizer class you load from this checkpoint is 'PreTrainedTokenizerFast'.
The class this function is called from is 'LlamaTokenizer'."
I am using the Huggingface API to directly load a model from HF Hub to sagemaker code editor using an ml.g5xlarge instance type in AWS. There is no tokenizer necessary or exposed using the HF API.

Did you find solution?

I found same question in the huggingface forum (https://huggingface.co/meta-llama/Meta-Llama-3-8B-Instruct/discussions/37), and the answer is to use "AutoTokenizer". Please try it.

This does not work. I get sam issue deploying model on Sagemaker. You don't need tokenizer to deploy the model.
